# Get App Deauthorize Callback

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I need to get `Deauthorize Callback` URL using FB App Id and Secret. Is it possible? I've looked at FQL, but didn't find anything. Basically, I want to disable script if Deauthorization Callback is not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible using the [Application endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application) in the Open Graph API. The field you are looking for is `deauth_callback_url`. The Application endpoint was [announced in December, 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/).

Answer (score 1):

We can set Deauthorize Callback url from Advanced Settings of APP.

To Get App Deauthorize Callback:
field-deauth_callback_url
Description: URL that is pinged whenever a user removes the app
Required:App access_token required; 
Returns: return "string"( only returned if specifically requested via the fields URL parameter)

Method:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/
     ?fields=deauth_callback_url
     &access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

For more information about app settings try this info page:
[APP Information Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/)